# Is $u^{\mu} = \gamma\tfrac{dx^{\mu}}{dt}$ a 4-vector?

Tags: general-relativity, special-relativity, vectors, velocity

I understand that $c\dfrac{dx^{\mu}}{ds}$ is a 4-vector since $ds$ is a scalar. In flat space-time,
$$
ds = c\dfrac{dt}{\gamma}
$$

so $\gamma\dfrac{dx^{\mu}}{dt}$ would be a 4-vector as it is equal to $c\dfrac{dx^{\mu}}{ds}$.

But in curved space-time, the books stop referring to $\gamma\dfrac{dx^{\mu}}{dt}$ when talking about 4-velocity. They opt to talk about $c\dfrac{dx^{\mu}}{ds}$.

Is this because $\gamma\dfrac{dx^{\mu}}{dt}$ is not a vector in curved space-time? If it was, is there any physical reason why it doesn't show up in the equations anymore?

Comment: It is still a vector. The reason why we define it just by $dx^a/d\sigma$ is that now  $\sigma$ can be set arbitrarily depending on choice of coordinates/set up and need not necessarily be proper time.